# Copy From CSV - COLUMN FAMILY NOT FOUND

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I've spent the past two days checking the available answers on this site and a few other sites.
I need help with the following (`COPY FROM` a CSV file) issue I'm encountering. I created the `KEYSPACE` and `COLUMN FAMILY` without any issues, but I receive a `COLUMN FAMILY NOT FOUND` when I attempt to copy a CSV file into the Table/Column Family. I've included the syntax I'm using below. I would truly appreciate help with resolving this matter. (Cassandra 2.0.6, CQL3.1.1)

I'm new to CQLSH.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE KS_TERA
  WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };

CREATE COLUMNFAMILY TERA
         (BIT_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    YEAR int ,  
    DAY_OF_MONTH int ,
    BIT_DATE timestamp ,
    COMP_ID int ,
    CARRIER varchar ,
    CARRIER_NUM int ,
    ORIGIN_SHIP_ID int 
         )
          WITH COMPACT STORAGE;

COPY TERA FROM ‘TERA.CSV’  WITH DELIMITER = ‘,’ AND HEADER = FALSE;
```

I get a `COLUMN FAMILY NOT FOUND` error.

Comment: Make sure you executed ``USE KS_TERA`` before executing ``COPY``

Answer (score 2):

That's because `COPY` command is case sensitive, you must replace the name of table (column family) and its columns in your command like this:

```
COPY tera FROM ‘TERA.CSV’  WITH DELIMITER = ‘,’ AND HEADER = FALSE;
```

if you have columns, then like this:

```
COPY tera (column1, column2, ... , columnn) FROM ‘TERA.CSV’  WITH DELIMITER = ‘,’ AND HEADER = FALSE;
```

Hope it helps to someone now...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the below query for copying into column-family? if not then try it will work as per your expectation.

```
COPY keyspace.columnfamily1 (column1, column2,...) TO 'temp.csv';
COPY keyspace.columnfamily2 (column1, column2,...) FROM 'temp.csv';
```